# How to add link href in Ant design alert component

Tags: react-native, antd, ant-design-pro

```
<Alert
  className={}
  onClick={(event) => {
     event.stopPropagration();
}}
message=“ test”
description = “want to add link “ 
type=“success”
/>
```

I want to add a link in description I tried  didn’t work for me

Comment: What have you tried? According to the docs the `description` prop takes a `ReactNode` value. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have tried adding <Link> and href but that doesn’t work in this case

Comment: What is `Link` in that case? Please share the code you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PoojaRayChaudhuri are you navigating the user to another page using react router? or you want to open a new website using link (`<a href="/link">link</a>`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add anchor/Link tag in your description

```
<Alert
  className={}
  onClick={(event) => {
     event.stopPropagration();
}}
message=“ test”
description = {<span>want to add <a href="/home"> link </a> </span> }
type=“success”
/>
```